# Jquery loading Ajax only works on first node in view unless clicking any other node first

Tags: ajax, javascript

I have a view of nodes. Each node has a table and a div. I would like to click a link to show an extra row in that node's table along with loading content via ajax into the div. Later the click should hide the extra row and div.

The code I have works correctly if the first node I click on is anything other than the first node in the list. If I click the first node in the list, none of the links in the other nodes will work. It's as if clicking the link in the first node of the list disables jquery from there on. Here's the code:

```
     Drupal.behaviors.ajaxview = function(context) {
  $('a.morelink:not(.ajaxview-processed)', context)
  .addClass('ajaxview-processed').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
$index = $('a.morelink').index($(this));
if ($('.xtrarow').eq($index).is(":hidden"))
 {
   $('.xtrarow').eq($index).show();
      var target = $('.col2').eq($index)
      var nrefcount = $(".mynrefcount").eq($index).val();
      var nid = $(".mynid").eq($index).val();
      var placeholder = '0';
       if(nrefcount == placeholder)
{var toLoad = Drupal.settings.basePath + 'content/no-replies';}
else
{var toLoad = Drupal.settings.basePath + 'replies/' + nid;}
            xhr = $.ajax({
        url: toLoad,
        success: function(data) {
          $(target).html($('.audioforumtable', data));
          Drupal.attachBehaviors(context);      }
      });
} else {
       $('.xtrarow').eq($('a.morelink').index($(this))).hide();
       }
     });
  });
```

What am I doing wrong?